# What is the gender of Chrona of Soul Eater?

Tags: soul-eater

Well, I picked this manga when I saw that its publication ended, but after few chapters I noticed that Chrona gender changed! (No, not the litteral) So, is this intended of the author, or I just missed some translator note somewhere?

Comment: I know certain translators had notes or note pages at the end of their chapter stating they're only going to refer to Chrona in a specific pronoun since there was no foreseeable sign of knowing. Others simply stuck with "it."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrona's gender was never revealed in the Japanese Soul Eater manga. There is evidence for both genders but not enough for either to make any conclusive statement. The creator has been asked what Chrona's gender is, but never answered.

In Japanese, this isn't hard to do. Most pronouns aren't gender-specific. While Chrona does use *boku* (僕) to refer to him/herself, which is a fairly masculine pronoun, it is sometimes used by females as well. However, in English (and many other languages), it's awkward to try to avoid using any gender-specific pronouns. The various different versions of Soul Eater in English use different pronouns, but all of these were added by translators and not present in the original version.

The [official Japanese Soul Eater site](http://www.souleater.tv/character/index.html) confirms that this is not known:

> 性別は不詳。

which literally translates to "Gender is unknown".

Comment: @Braiam I don't see what you consider a spoiler in the above. It certainly doesn't reveal any future plot points from the story. In any case, you may want to read our [policy on spoilers](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policy-be-regarding-spoilers).

Comment: @Braiam its not a spoiler, crona's gender holds no specific plot points (maybe some jokes will be less funny) but dont see it as a spoiler

Answer (score 0):

In the anime Crona is exclusively referred to as a "he."  However, in the manga "his" gender is purposefully kept unsaid.

Comment: Could you state if this is from the original Japanese, official English-translated (if exists), or fansub/scanlation?